# Return index of original matrix that was transformed in a diagonal list - Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, matrix, diagonal

Originally I have a wordsearch puzzle and my goal is to find the words in it given a previous list of words. I was able to successfully find the words in the horizontal and vertical lines, but I'm having trouble find the diagonals.

My main ideia is to take my input of letters and join then in a one big string and then search for the word in this string, returning the line the word belongs to, and after that I just check where it starts, and so on.

For my diagonals I was planning the same, but let's say this is my input:

```
c l i o a
e a g b e
a r t l s
j i a u a
e e q u b
e u g r r
c i d e p
b i o s b
2
cat
big
```

Once I convert my diagonals in a joined list this is what I get:

```
# first diagonal
first_diag = ['b', 'ci', 'eio', 'euds', 'jegeb', 'aiqrp', 'eraur', 'catub', 'lgla', 'ibs', 'oe', 'a']

# second diagonal
sec_diag = ['c', 'le', 'iaa', 'ogrj', 'abtie', 'elaee', 'suquc', 'augib', 'brdi', 'reo', 'ps', 'b']
```

From that I would take where in my original puzzle the word `"cat"` is in row (0) and column (0). The same for the word `"big"` [8][0].

Expected output:

```
c . . . .
. a . . .
. . t . .
. . . . .
. . . . .
. . g . .
. i . . .
b . . . .
```

How can I do that, or is there another way to do it? tnx in advance.

edit: If needed, I can post the code I have.

Comment: Perhaps the code would be needed sooner or later - but at first it's not really clear what you already have and what is your problem you want to ask here. e.g. the first and second diagonal - does the algorithm already exist or not - or not in a way you like...?

Comment: Will edit, but what I have is this list of diagonals, both. And I want to return the index telling me where, in my original puzzle the words start. I also can check where in my list of diagonals the word is, by simply doing `"cat" in first_mat[i]` for example. In this case `i = 7` but it does not start in row 7, but row 0. The same happens for checking columns. Hope I made myself clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first I'd store the row-/column- values of the diagonal strings in four arrays.
Let's say, your matrix has nr rows and nc columns, then

```
first_diag_r = [max(nr - 1 - i, 0) for i, _ in enumerate(first_diag)]
```

and

```
first_diag_c = [min(i, nc - 1) for i, _ in enumerate(first_diag)]
```

and accordingly for the second_diag.

Now, if you find a word in there, which is not at the beginning of a diagonal string like your two examples above, this offset has to be calculated:
For the first_diag this means adding offset to column value and substracting offset from row value.